# Локализация андроид приложения

Tags: java, android, locale

Внизу приложения есть кнопка при нажатии на которую меняется язык с "русского"(по умолчанию) на "английский". для изменения локали написал такой код:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.locale = locale;
context.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, null);
recreate();
```

Все окей язык меняется но если выйти из приложения и заново зайти то язык опять же по умолчанию. Что же нужно сделать чтобы локаль не менялась при перезагрузки приложения?

Comment: @croll  это как?

Comment: использовать SharedPreferences (http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php)?

Comment: @sapeg да я уже так и сделал просто я думал можно один раз написать и в следущий раз будет выбранный язык

Comment: ............Ok.